# VLC is unable to open the MRL in android

Tags: android, udp, libvlc, vlc-android

I have integrated `vlclib` in my app to play video stream in following way

```
    try {
        mMediaPlayer = VLCInstance.getLibVlcInstance();
    } catch (LibVlcException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    mMediaPlayer.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);
    EventHandler em = EventHandler.getInstance();
    em.addHandler(mVlcHandler);

    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mSurfaceView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    mMediaPlayer.playMRL("udp://@192.168.0.104:1234");
```

When I try to play any `rtsp` streaming like `rtsp://192.168.0.10:8554/ss`  but when I try to play any `udp` streaming I got **VLC is unable to open the MRL 'udp://@192.168.0.104:1234'.**

Answer (score 0):

Use this : `udp://@:1234`.

Just in case VLC tries using IPv6, use `udp://@0.0.0.0:1234`.